# Error with \usepackage pdfpages and \chapter

Tags: errors, chapters, pdfpages

I'm trying to include some pdf pages into my report, however when I add `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, any \chapter occurance will give me the following error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero \chapter{hi}
Color stack action is missing \chapter{hi}
```

I'm using TexLive 2013, TexStudio and Windows 8.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\par%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{-3pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{-3pt}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}   
\addbibresource{refs2.bib}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{hi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is an MWE? Kindly remove the numerous `\usepackage` and other commands one at a time and then leave the minimum ones which still create your said problem. Perhaps that will even help you to isolate the offending one by yourself and find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `pgfpages`; you are using `\MakeUppercase` in the wrong way: `\MakeUppercase` receives a mandatory argument. If you want to use \MakeUppercase for the chapter titles, then you can use the `explicit` option for `titlesec` which gives you access to the title through a parameter that can be used as the argument for `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\par%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{-3pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{-3pt}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}   
\addbibresource{refs2.bib}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{hi}
\end{document}
```

By the way, instead of using upper case for the titles, I'd suggest you to use small caps instead; if you are forced to use upper case, please consider `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package which won't use upper case for special charcaters (math, labels, etc.).

Comment: Thanks you, problem solved. The weird thing is without `\usepackage{pdfpages}` it works just fine before (chapter title are uppercase etc). Anyway thanks!